# Swift error: failed to get module 'My_App' from AST context

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, cocoapods, lldb

I'm using Swift 3, Xcode 8.1, CocoaPods 1.1.1. After running `pod update`, every time i try to use Xcode's lldb console - it prints an error.
 For example, `po self` outputs:

> Shared Swift state for *My App* has developed fatal errors and is being discarded.
>   REPL definitions and persistent names/types will be lost.
>   warning: Swift error in module *My App*.
>   Debug info from this module will be unavailable in the debugger.
>   error: in auto-import:
>   failed to get module '*My_App*' from AST context:

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score -2):

Swift doesn't currently support debugging pre-built (i.e. built on another machine) Swift binaries.  Make sure that you build all the CocoaPods modules you are using locally.  If that doesn't fix the problem, please file a bug with http://bugs.swift.org or Apple's bug reporter http://bugreporter.apple.com.

Comment: how to do this ? Wasn't the whole point of cocoapods of exactly not doing this ? the ecosystem has become such a pain to use lately

Comment: How do you build the CocoaPod modules locally?

Comment: @Jim what do you mean .by "build all the CocoaPods modules you are using locally."?

Comment: From what I can tell on the Cocoapods site, they always build from source now-a-days.  That's not true of Carthage - there when you update you have to explicitly say you want to rebuild from source and not get the pre-built binaries. My memory is that CocoaPods also used to have pre-built binaries, but I could be wrong about that.